# pyspark how to write UDF using two columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

```
rdd = sc.parallelize( [(['a','b','c'], 'c'), \
                       (['h','j','s'], 'j'), \
                       (['w','x','a'], 'a'), \
                       (['o','b','e'], 'c')] )

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, ['seq','target'])

+---------+------+
|      seq|target|
+---------+------+
|[a, b, c]|     c|
|[h, j, s]|     j|
|[w, x, a]|     a|
|[o, b, e]|     c|
+---------+------+
```

I want to write an UDF to remove the target from seq.

```
+---------+------+---------+
|      seq|target| filtered|
+---------+------+---------+
|[a, b, c]|     c|   [a, b]|
|[h, j, s]|     j|   [h, s]|
|[w, x, a]|     a|   [w, x]|
|[o, b, e]|     c|[o, b, e]|
+---------+------+---------+
```

Note that this is just a showcase. The practical case is more complex. I want to get the formal way to process one column, such as `seq` by using another column, such as `target`, as a parameter.
Any generalized solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_remove`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('filtered', F.expr('array_remove(seq, target)'))

df2.show()
+---------+------+---------+
|      seq|target| filtered|
+---------+------+---------+
|[a, b, c]|     c|   [a, b]|
|[h, j, s]|     j|   [h, s]|
|[w, x, a]|     a|   [w, x]|
|[o, b, e]|     c|[o, b, e]|
+---------+------+---------+
```

If you're looking for a UDF solution,

```
@F.udf('array<string>')
def array_remove(col1, col2):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x != col2, col1))

df2 = df.withColumn('filtered', array_remove('seq', 'target'))

df2.show()
+---------+------+---------+
|      seq|target| filtered|
+---------+------+---------+
|[a, b, c]|     c|   [a, b]|
|[h, j, s]|     j|   [h, s]|
|[w, x, a]|     a|   [w, x]|
|[o, b, e]|     c|[o, b, e]|
+---------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you use the expression `array_remove` instead of function? Is this `'array<string>'` equivalent to `T.ArrayType(T.StringType())`? What kind of notation is this?

Comment: @MykolaZotko the function does not accept a column as the second parameter, so I needed to use expr. yes for the second question, it's how you specify types in SQL

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does it also work in the scenario of more than two columns ? @mck

Comment: @yanachen yes, just put more columns in the function arguments